# Quote from ancient scholar: that a leader cannot be neutral, he must chose a side

Tags: quote

An ancient scholar said a leader cannot be neutral, that he must chose a side or he will be viewed as an enemy by both sides.

I am trying to find who said/wrote that. Anyone know? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "everyone."  First hit included:

“The hottest places in hell are reserved for those who, in times of great moral crisis, maintain their neutrality.” 
― Dante Alighieri

“If you are neutral in situations of injustice, you have chosen the side of the oppressor. If an elephant has its foot on the tail of a mouse, and you say that you are neutral, the mouse will not appreciate your neutrality.” 
― Desmond Tutu (Foreword)

“Neutrality wears upon it the bias dress, whether direct or indirect way since no one shows and proves naturally or habitually, to be a natural. It demonstrates a legal, virtuous and impeccable idiocy.” 
― Ehsan Sehgal

Comment: Dante's "quote" is (at least) spurious, actually the *ignavi* (indolents) are placed in the very first section of Inferno, where the temperature is milder ("From his bounds Heaven drove them forth/Not to impair his lustre; nor the depth/Of Hell receives them, lest the accursed tribe/Should glory thence with exultation vain"). So Dante's view is completely opposite: they didn't even deserve a real punishment ("These have no longer any hope of death;\⁠And this blind life of theirs is so debased,\⁠They envious are of every other fate"). Maybe are you quoting Dan Brown's Inferno?